# Programmatically Setting Top Shelf Image on tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I am curious to know if anyone has had any success programmatically setting a Top Shelf image in a tvOS app?  I've read through a few tutorials (such as [this one](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tvos-tutorial-top-shelf/)) that details setting the Top Shelf image in either a `sectioned` or `inset` style, but I'm curious if anyone knows a way to choose a static image (in the 1920x720 resolution), based on a set of criteria.  I'm interested in choosing a different 1920x720 image based on time of day.

I've played around a bit with the `TVTopShelfProvider` class, but I'm not seeing a way to choose anything but the bundled image in your assets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `TVTopShelfProvider` you can supply content which with points to a local image on the device or an image somewhere on the internet. This is done with the `imageURL` of the `TVContentItem` returned in `topShelfItems`. Whenever you change the contents of `topShelfItems` you need to post `TVTopShelfItemsDidChangeNotification` so the device knows that an update is required.

Comment: Note that it isn't guaranteed to update the top shelf immediately and that the time taken isn't documented, that I'm aware of...

Comment: Thanks, @Wain.  All I see in `TVTopShelfProvider` is the option is set either a `sectioned` or `inset` style, though, whereas I would prefer neither (I only want one static image in the full 1920x720 resolution, which is the size that appears if you do not implement `TVTopShelfProvider` framework altogether).  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's the fallback of you don't provide any `topShelfItems`. Not sure you can change that, or get exactly the same style.

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ indeed if you are using the "simple static image in icons file" approach. There's NO WAY to change it dynamically. Unless there has been a major development recently.

Answer (score 0):

There are two completely different approaches to the Top Shelf.

1. use the 1920.720 (and 2x that) image, which is simply in the icons assets of the normal app
2. create a TV Top Shelf extension, which is a whole app unto itself

If you are using "1" - "just an image in the icons file" - in fact it seems there is NO WAY to dynamically set that image. It's just a static image, exactly like (say) the app icon.

Maybe this has changed recently, but that seems to be the situation.